# Translation Golf XXIV - Go East or Go West?

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

Welcome to a new edition of the game!
If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

Esta ocasión nos vamos al este... hasta la China para volver al Oeste. Para el juego traemos el cuento "Viaje al Oeste" de *Wu Ch’eng-en*. Uno de los 4 clásicos de la literatura china.

Si bien el texto en chino está presente en varios sitios, mi desconocimiento del idioma original (y creo no ser el único) me lleva a elegir la versión traducida al [inglés](https://chine.in/fichiers/jourwest.pdf) de la parte del libro que deseo, en el capítulo 7. Aquí el Rey Mono está destruyendo el palacio real del Emperador de Jade para hacerse con el poder, contra todos los ejércitos de las deidades lo que lleva a que el Buda Tathagata hable con él:

> "What have you got, besides immortality and the ability to transform yourself, that gives you the nerve to try
>   to seize the Heavenly Palace?" the Buddha asked.
>
> "I can do many tricks indeed," the Great Sage replied. "I can perform seventy−two transformations, and I can
>   preserve my youth for ten thousand kalpas. I can ride a somersault cloud that takes me thirty−six thousand
>   miles at a single jump. So why shouldn't I sit on the throne of Heaven?"
>
> "I'll have a wager with you then," said the Buddha. "If you're clever enough to get out of my right hand with a
>   single somersault, you will be the winner, and there will be no more need for weapons or fighting: I shall
>   invite the Jade Emperor to come and live in the West and abdicate the Heavenly Palace to you. But if you
>   can't get out of the palm of my hand you will have to go down to the world below as a devil and train yourself
>   for several more kalpas before coming to argue about it again."

Una traducción publicada [en español](https://deymerg.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/viaje-al-oeste-las-aventuras-del-rey-mono.pdf) dice:

> "Aparte de la inmortalidad y de tu capacidad metamórfica, ¿qué otros poderes posees para osar usurpar el trono de esta región santa?" preguntó el Patriarca Budista.  -
> "¡Muchísimos!" contestó el Gran Sabio con rapidez. "Domino setenta y dos transformaciones y poseo una vida que se mantendrá inmutable durante más de diez mil *kalpas*. Sé, además, andar por las nubes y con un solo salto soy capaz de desplazarme a una distancia de ciento ocho mil kilómetros. ¿Te parece poco para que pueda ocupar el trono del cielo?"  -
> "Hagamos una apuesta" replicó el Patriarca Budista. "Si eres capaz de caer de mi mano derecha de un solo salto, te consideraremos todos el vencedor. No tendrás que seguir guerreando, porque yo mismo pediré al Emperador de Jade que se venga a vivir conmigo al oeste y te deje a ti el Palacio Celeste. Si, por el contrario, eres incapaz de abandonar la palma de mi mano, regresarás a las Regiones Inferiores, donde deberás someterte a unas cuantas *kalpas* más, antes de volver a causar problemas."
>  
>  <sub>(803 caracteres)</sub>

Las diferencias entre textos se notan por ser publicados en inglés y en español (no es traducción mía la versión en español, la dejo para el fuera de concurso) y a pesar del tamaño inicial se ve muy golfeable... y de veras llama la atención esta *anécdota* de lo que hace el Rey Mono.

Nota: *Kalpa* es un periodo de tiempo largo (con mayúsculas y a alargada) en el budismo o en el hinduismo. Al no ser un término en español, podrán adaptarlo o usarlo como extranjerismo.

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Éxitos a todos y a lucirse planteando la mejor traducción con menos caracteres.

And finally, in the column of the middle he wrote " @Charlie has won the game ". Congrats @Charlie

Comment: Interesante y original elección. No se si lo has hecho ya pero he pedido que pongan la pregunta como wiki.

Comment: Tengo una duda con *somersault cloud*. *Somersault* es voltereta, acrobacia o algo así pero no se como poner *somersault cloud*: ¿nube acrobática? Me suena un poco raro. De momento he puesto nube sin más.

Comment: @blonfu si bien Sun wu kun tiene su 'nube voladora', puede realizar largos saltos por las nubes

Comment: Sí, pero dice *ride a somersault cloud*. Habla de una sola nube que le lleva muy lejos.

Comment: gracias por  el juego limpio... juego cerrado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### <strike>435 372 318 294</strike> 285 caracteres

> —No mueres, [trasmutas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aSvQ4Qo), ¿con qué más tomarás el Palacio [Etéreo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=H3TkRvw)? —dijo el Buda.
>        —Tengo 72 trasmutaciones —dijo el Gran Sabio—, seré joven por mil eones, salto y vuelo 36000 millas, y más. Su trono ha de ser mío.
>        —Apostémoslo. Sé listo, salta fuera de mi mano derecha, y en paz lo tendrás: el Rey de Jade vendrá al Oeste. Si no, huye, orco, al mundo abajo, entrena más eones, y vuelve.

Explicaciones:

- "I can do many tricks indeed" se sustituye por el "y más" al final de la respuesta.
- No es necesario preservar la medida exacta de tiempo de 10000 *kalpas*, sino solo dar la idea de un periodo de tiempo muy grande. Además, [hay cuatro tipos de *kalpa*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa) y en el texto no se menciona cuál es, por lo cual el texto original queda también impreciso.
- "Su trono" es el del Palacio Celestial, mencionado previamente.
- Al decir que "el Rey de Jade vendrá al Oeste" se entiende la parte de que "lo invitará".
- Explicación de "[orco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R9L2PwR)": según su etimología proviene del latín *Orcus* 'Plutón', 'ultratumba', 'muerte'. De ahí vino "[huerco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KlEf7A4)", de la cual es sinónima, y entre cuyos significados está "diablo".
- Si no se introduce ningún personaje más, se entiende que la tercera frase la dice el mismo personaje que la primera.

Answer (score 5):

#### <s>636 531 488 428 395 353 310</s> 289 caracteres

> BUDA: ¿Tienes la jeta de venir a ocupar el Templo Divino, por mutante
>   sin fin?
>
> GRAN SABIO: [Ja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MFgNyz8)! 72 cambios,10 000 kalpas de zagal y 36 000 millas en un
>   salto de nube valen el trono.
>
> BUDA: Salta de mi [derecha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CGv2o6x) y se acaba la pelea, invoco al Rey de Jade,
>   viene a vivir al Oeste y te da el templo, si fallas irás al mundo cual
>   diablo y [avíate](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4ZNca8Z%7C4ZOJgV6) [pila](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sz7DDE4%7CSz7PRrG) de kalpas antes de volver al asunto.

Comment: @walen tienes razón. Como había puesto "mundo inferior" se me ha ido la olla en el último cambio, por olvidarme del original

Answer (score 5):

#### <s>378</s> 296

> *"¿Osas tomar Villa Cielo con vida eterna, transmutación, y ya?"*, fue Buda.
>
> Y el Gran Sabio: *"He más: 72 mutaciones, ser mozo 10 000 eones, botar 36 000 millas en una nube. ¿Por qué no el trono Celeste?"*
>
> Y Buda: *"Juguemos. Si sales de mi diestra de un bote, no más guerra: el Rey Jade al oeste, y tu a Villa Cielo. Si no, volverás diablo a la Tierra, y fin del tema hasta que entrenes varios eones más."*

Comment: vaya disminución... pero no me suena el fue ¿Puedes poner la acepción del verbo ser o ir? (o si me equivoco de verbo, ya que el DRAE no me ayudó a primera vista)